# Python astimezone() unexpected result

Tags: python, datetime

Given a variable containing the datetime of 2000-01-01 00:01 in Paris timezone (UTC+2 in winter afaik):

```
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))
```

I expected the conversion to UTC to result in a datetime of 1999-12-31 22:01, but got instead:

```
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')).astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 31, 23, 52, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Unfortunately using the `tzinfo` argument of the standard `datetime`
>   constructors ‘’does not work’’ with `pytz` for many timezones.
>
> ```
> >>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=amsterdam).strftime(fmt)
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 LMT+0020'
> ```
>
> It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though, such as UTC:
>
> ```
> >>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc).strftime(fmt)
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 UTC+0000'
> ```

As you'll notice:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 1, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' LMT+0:09:00 STD>)
```

"LMT+0:09:00 STD"…?! That's a historical offset, not a current standard.

The timezone bundles (containing all historical offsets since forever) returned by `pytz` aren't handled correctly by `datetime`, and it chooses some random (well, the *first* probably) offset instead of the offset pertinent to the actual time. Arguably, since it needs to interpret the time correctly first it cannot choose the right offset by time from the timezone bundle.

> This library only supports two ways of building a localized time. The
>   first is to use the `localize()` method provided by the `pytz` library.
>   This is used to localize a naive `datetime` (`datetime` with no timezone
>   information):
>
> ```
> >>> loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
> >>> print(loc_dt.strftime(fmt))
> 2002-10-27 06:00:00 EST-0500
> ```
>
> The second way of building a localized time is by converting an existing
>   localized time using the standard `astimezone()` method:
>
> ```
> >>> ams_dt = loc_dt.astimezone(amsterdam)
> >>> ams_dt.strftime(fmt)
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 CET+0100'
> ```
>
> http://pytz.sourceforge.net